# strange problem with WriteBeginTag

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, render

i use such code, but it renders with error `<li class="dd0"><div id="dt1"<a href="http://localhost:1675/Category/29-books.aspx">Books</a></div></li>`

there is no `>` in opening tag div. what the problem?

```
writer.WriteBeginTag("li");
                //writer.WriteAttribute("class", this.CssClass);
                writer.WriteAttribute("class", "dd0");
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LiLeftMargin))
                {
                    writer.WriteAttribute("style", string.Format("margin-left: {0}px", this.LiLeftMargin));
                }
                writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
                writer.WriteBeginTag("div");
                writer.WriteAttribute("id", "dt1");
                this.HyperLink.RenderControl(writer);
                writer.WriteEndTag("div");
                writer.WriteEndTag("li");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use *writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);*, the writer is intelligent enough to close the tags. Again when using <strike>Write</strike>RenderEndTag, you dont need to supply a parameter.

Edit. Im talking about different methods here. Here is the code I would use:

```
    output.AddAttribute("class", "dd0");

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LiLeftMargin))
    {
        output.AddAttribute("style", string.Format("margin-left: {0}px", LiLeftMargin));
    }

    output.RenderBeginTag("li");

    //output.Write(HtmlTextoutput.TagRightChar);
    output.AddAttribute("id", "dt1");
    output.RenderBeginTag("div");

    this.HyperLink.RenderControl(output);

    output.RenderEndTag(); //div
    output.RenderEndTag(); //li
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a call to `writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar)` after you have written your attributes (like you have already done for the `li` element):

```
writer.WriteBeginTag("div");
writer.WriteAttribute("id", "dt1");
writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagRightChar);
```

The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.writebegintag.aspx) for `WriteBeginTag` explicitly state this behaviour:

> The WriteBeginTag method does not write the closing angle bracket (>) of the markup element's opening tag. This allows the writing of markup attributes to the opening tag of the element. Use the TagRightChar constant to close the opening tag when calling the WriteBeginTag method.

Comment: Just for reference (as it doesn't apply in your case), you can use `WriteFullBeginTag` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.writefullbegintag(v=VS.90).aspx) to output the closing `<` if you don't need to output any attributes on the element.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can just do this:

```
output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, "dt1");
output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
output.RenderEndTag();
```

Which will create the result you want. It's important to put the `AddAttribute` before the `RenderbeginTag` or the Attribute will not appear!

I think this method is a lot neater.